# AG Grid Master Detail expand collapse child rows

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am using AG Grid Master detail.  there are three levels of grid.

How could I expand or collapse inner levels of detail grid. the below code helps only to control parent level grid

```
        this.gridApi.forEachNode(function (node) {
          if (node.data.empid=== id) {
            node.setExpanded(true);
            node.setSelected(true);
 //how to drill down to further nodes and expand or collapse them ?
          }
    });
```

data is in the below format

```
  {
    "CountryId": "AB123",
    "Name": "India",
    "States": [
      {
        "CountryId": "AB123",
        "StateId": "AD30E66E",
        "Name": "Telangana",
        "Population": "100000",
        "Description": "asdf adsf",
        "Regions": [
          {
            "StateId": "AD30E66E",
            "RegionName": "Nizamabad",
            "Population": "22222",
            "Description": "Test Description Two"
          }
        ]
      }]}
```